# Handling NULL values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, union, null

I am using QGIS to make some boundaries adjustments of the Italian provinces over the years. I have a shapefile with the provincial boundaries in 1961 and another one with the boundaries in 2001. No value is missing in these shapefiles. However, when I use "Union", I get some NULL values. Why does this happen? And how can I handle them?

Comment: Silvia, what fields are causing the NULL values, can you share a snapshot of the attribute table(s) (both before and joined after)?

Comment: If you are using an overlay layer in the algorithm then I believe the Null values indicate that it does not share any overlapping geometry with the input vectors but I would need to see an example of your inputs and outputs to confirm what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Shapefiles cannot store NULL values since the database is dBase III format.  This may just be a default setting in QGIS that represents blank values as NULL.  Look under Settings (menu)>Options>Data Sources and remove the NULL value text.

[image]